# jQuery Deferreds - Pass result of $.when to $.then

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm starting to use jQuery Deferred objects a bit more and I run into this issue:

I have a central AJAX function that performs pre validation of data, ajax set up and a few other things that sends to the server and returns xyz as data. How do I access 'xyz' in the 'then' part of a $.when(ajaxfn).then(dosomethingwithresult()); I get that ajaxfn returns a deferred object, but is there any way to pass the xhr's responseText forward?

I'm essentially doing it like this...

```
function ajaxfn(data) {
prevalidate(data);
return $.ajax(settings);
}
$.when(ajaxfn).then(function() {
// put 'xyz' on the page somewhere.
});
```

At the moment I'm just passing in a $.data pointer to the ajaxfn, and then in the success of the ajax request, I have $('body',pos,result) and then access it like that from inside then $('body).data(pos) == xyz. I'd like to know if there's a better way of doing what I've described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.when(ajaxfn()).then(function(data) {
    // put 'xyz' on the page somewhere.
});
```

Comment: Ok.... lol, I actually had tried that before and it didn't work at all... I must have had some JS error somewhere that wasn't getting put on the console that stopped it before it got to that part. Lol, thanks! I also made it .then(function(data, event) to return success/fail from the ajax request);

Answer (score 2):

This can be simplified like so:

```
function ajaxfn(data) {
    prevalidate(data);
    return $.ajax(settings);
}

ajaxfn().then(function(response) {
    console.debug(response);
});
```

There is no need to use a `$.when` object.  The ajax is already returning a promise.